# Cannot rm/unlink files at first but can after vim and writing the file

Tags: nfs, selinux, vagrant

**NOTE:** It looks like setting selinux to Permissive mode does not prevent this file permission issue.

We have a development VM running CentOs 7.2.1511. Files are shared with our host machines (Macs) via NFS via vagrant (virtualbox).

The NFS share is so we can edit the code using PHPStorm on our host machines. The issue does not crop up if we use SMB shares but then the file share r/w performance is undesirably slow.

The share setting in vagrant is:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "code", "/srv/client/code" , :nfs=>true, :mount_options => ['rw,noatime,nolock,vers=3,udp,fsc,actimeo=2,resvport,rsize=32768,wsize=32768']
```

Sporadically when running `git checkout x` or `git clean -df`, we will receive permission denied messages.

```
$ git clean -df
warning: failed to remove modules/node_modules/acorn/bin/acorn
warning: failed to remove modules/node_modules/acorn/bin/generate-identifier-regex.js
...
```

Running `ls -Z modules/node_modules/acorn/bin/acorn`

```
$ ls -Z modules/node_modules/acorn/bin/acorn
-rwxr-xr-x. 503 games system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0       modules/node_modules/acorn/bin/acorn
```

Which is the correct user/group for the share as well as the correct file context, and exactly the same as a file which is removable.
e.g.

```
$ ls -Z composer.json
-rw-rw-r--. 503 games system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0       composer.json
```

If we try to remove the now oddly permissioned file directly then we get permission denied.

```
$ rm modules/node_modules/acorn/bin/acorn
rm: cannot remove ‘modules/node_modules/acorn/bin/acorn’: Permission denied
```

However, if we vi the file and write (even without making any editable changes) 
i.e.

- `vi modules/node_modules/acorn/bin/acorn`
- `:w`
- `rm modules/node_modules/acorn/bin/acorn` will work correctly.

Alternatively, if we check out the relevant files/directories from the host machine then the issues disappear and we can rm the files again.

Would anyone have any idea why this file permission pops up sporadically ? and how we might fix it ?

**Update (27-01-2017)** *[at the request of embedded]:*

The output of running `$ mount` re: the nfs share is:

```
10.20.30.1:/Path/to/code on /guest/path/code type nfs (rw,noatime,vers=3,rsize=16384,wsize=16384,namlen=255,acregmin=2,acregmax=2,acdirmin=2,acdirmax=2,hard,nolock,proto=udp,timeo=11,retrans=3,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.20.30.1,mountvers=3,mountport=839,mountproto=udp,fsc,local_lock=all,addr=10.20.30.1)
```

**Update(29-01-2017)** *[at the request of lauc.exon.nod]:*

Have run `sudo setenforce Permissive`

```
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

Still unable to delete previously errored file:

```
$ rm /guest/path/code/vendor/twig/twig/doc/filters/abs.rst
rm: cannot remove ‘/guest/path/code/vendor/twig/twig/doc/filters/abs.rst’: Permission denied
$ ls -Z /guest/path/code/vendor/twig/twig/doc/filters/abs.rst
-rw-rw-r--. 503 games system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0       /guest/path/code/vendor/twig/twig/doc/filters/abs.rst
```

Cleared this error by removing the affected files from the host, and then was able to reproduce the error again with new files. **It looks like setting selinux to Permissive mode does not affect the NFS issue.**

**Update(31-01-2017)** *[at the request of mzhaase]:*

Touching a file with the permission issue does not clear the permission issue. A subsequent vim with :w did clear the permission issue and the file was then rm'ed correctly.

**Update(02-02-2017)** *[at the request of allo]:*

Attempted to `lsattr` a file with permission error. Unfortunately received `lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device...`. According to http://www.jpeek.com/articles/linuxmag/2008-07/ - Supported Filesystems - NFS mounts are not lsattr-able.

Comment: Please update the question and show the output of # mount
For the NFS share

Comment: Have added an update with output of mount specific to the nfs share at the bottom of the original description. Thanks!

Comment: for troubleshooting, please set the selinux to permissive mode and try again. if it works during permissive mode, than you would have to check for selinux labels.

Comment: If you do a `touch <filename>` does it also fix the permission error?

Comment: Touching the file does fix the permission error unfortunately.

Comment: Did you check the extended attributes (with ``lsattr``)? They can be used to forbid deletion/modifications and possible some programs remove them when saving.

Comment: Unfortunately received `lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device` - please see update in Desc for more info.